# How do I create always 4 digit sequentially numbered and named file with shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, files

I'm trying to create multiple *.txt files with 4-digit numerical names with leading zeros when needed.  Script needs to stop when MAX varialbe is reached.  This is using /bin/sh (not bash) but any help much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh
NUMBER=0001
MAX=0011
NUMBERFILE=$NUMBER".txt"
while [ $NUMBER -lt $MAX ]; do
    printf "\n$NUMBERFILE"
    # touch $NUMBERFILE
    NUMBER=$(( NUMBER+0001 ))
    NUMBERFILE=$NUMBER".txt"
done
printf "\n\nFINISHED!\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does not require any external tool from the shell, If you want an external tool then yes, seq is the answer!

```
#!/bin/sh

NUMBER=1
MAX=11
while [ $NUMBER -lt $MAX ]; do
  file=$(printf '%04d.%s\n' "$NUMBER" "txt")
  printf '%s\n' "Creating" "$file"
  touch "$file" 
  NUMBER=$(( NUMBER+1 ))
done
printf "\n\nFINISHED!\n\n"
```

The touch can be replaced with `>` if you just want to create an empty files.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

MIN=1
MAX=11
PADDING=4

for i in $(seq -f "%0${PADDING}g" $MIN $MAX); do
  file=${i}.txt
  printf "$file\n"
  touch $file
done

printf "\n\nFINISHED!\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
seq -f">%04g.txt" "$MIN" "$MAX" | . /dev/stdin
```